# Selenium webdriver : Unable to click a link (Not inside iframe- able to print gettext value from the webelement)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please don't make comments regarding why i posted a similar question. I have tried many things and nothing is working. Below is the HTML

```
    <div id="businessSettingsColumn1">
       <div class="sectionLink"> 

       <a href="serviceprovider/30015514/settings/details">Business details</a>
       </div>
      <div class="sectionLink">
        <a href="serviceprovider/30015514/settings/hours">Operating hours</a>
      </div>
     <div class="sectionLink">
     <a href="settingsserviceproviderleave.action?purpose=closed">Closed dates</a>
     </div>
     <div class="sectionLink">
      <a href="serviceprovider/30015514/settings/booking/notifications">Appointment            notifications</a>
  </div>
```

I need to click the second link
I have tried

1) `webdriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Operating hours")).click();`

2)`webDriver.get(mylement.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href"));`

3)

```
List<WebElement> businessLinks= busCol.findElements(By.className("sectionLink"));

    for(WebElement bLink :businessLinks) {
    if(bLink.getText().contains("Operating hours")) {

    bLink.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
    }
            }
```

4) Using the Action builder to move the mouse and then doing a click

Also when i did this 3 times in a row , my element got clicked

```
webdriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Operating hours")).click();
webdriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Operating hours")).click();
webdriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Operating hours")).click();
```

I am using Firefox version 25.0 and Selenium version 2.35.0. Funny thing though is when i do a sysout , the values get printed and when i try to get the url using webdriver I get "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" .. its pretty much a static page with links only so i dont understand why i am not able to click it.. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what could cause this.  There may be javascript that isn't getting fired?  Regardless, I would try clicking it with javascript, and I would also try clicking it once, and then waiting until the next element appears.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try calling focus() on the element before you click on it?

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs because the element was there at some point, but then something happened and then it's no longer there for some reason. I encounter this frequently when a page makes AJAX calls for example.

Have you tried adding some waits so that selenium is sure that the element is ready?

Comment: Thanks for answering :) but as i mentioned this is pretty much a static html page.. no ajax calls there.. Also i am able to print the values just before i click my element. I have also added waits but nothing seems to work. I have also tried using xpath , css nothing seem to work.

Comment: It is interesting that clicking three times in a row worked. It's obvious that you are getting the correct element. Does it only work when you click it three times? What about two? Does it consistently work when you click 3 times?

Comment: well i am encountering lots of weirdness here.. After it clicked when i put it 3 times in a row.. on each test execution i removed one line and checked .. it worked for two and then one...(just once) and when i ran the test again.. nothing happened (back to square 1 :()

Comment: When you do it manually you don't have to click the link twice I'm assuming.

Comment: Looks like clicking it twice does it.. i dont want to write a flaky test .. what do you suggest?

Comment: Perhaps opening the link directly for now (by grabbing the href attribute and opening the page directly)? That sort of defeats the purpose of the test if you are testing for clicks, but if you just need to get to the new page, I would just do that until I figure out what's wrong with the click.

Comment: Try updating selenium...I think the most recent is 2.37 or something. I've always had issues whenever Firefox decided to release a new version and was fixed by getting the patched selenium...